# How to serialize and deserialize a hash sent to a socket?

Tags: perl, sockets, serialization, hash, deserialization

I am writing two scripts: the client and the server. The client connects itself to the server and has to enter credentials. I want to send those credentials trough a hash, so I serialize them, send them to the server socket and then deserialize the hash in the server script.

Here is the relevant server script code:

```pl
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto => tcp,
    LocalPort => 25,
    Listen => SOMAXCONN,
    Reuse => 1) or die "cannot connect to port $port at localhost";
while (my $new_socket = $serveur->accept())
{
    $new_socket->autoflush(1);
    $line = <$new_socket>;
    my %hashUserInfos = %{thaw($line)};

    my $username = $hashInfosUtilisateur{'username'};
    my $password = $hashInfosUtilisateur{'password'};
}
```

And here is the relevant client script code:

```pl
my $connection = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => $protocol,
    PeerAddr => $destination,
    PeerPort => $port) or die "Impossible de se connecter sur le port $port a l'adresse $destination";

print "Nom d'usager:\n";
$username = <STDIN>;
print "Mot de passe:\n";

my $password = <STDIN>;
my $hashedPasword = md5_hex($password);

my %userInfos = ('username' => $username, 'password' => $hashedPassword);
my $serializedInfos = freeze \%userInfos;

print $connection $serializedInfos;
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I'm trying to deserialize the hash:

```
my %hashUserInfos = %{thaw($line)};
```

I'm getting the error:

> Magic number checking on storable string failed

I also tried serializing my hash with `nfreeze`, but in that case, I get this error instead of the one above:

> Can't use an undefined values as a HASH reference

What's the mistake I'm making here?

Comment: Have you tried printing the serialized hash in both the server and client and compare the outputs?

Comment: @choroba I did compare them, but while debugging. Their values were kind of incomprehensible, so I thought it was normal since they were serialized. The following pictures show the outputs of the serialized hashes in both the client and the server. However, it's another hash than the one in the question (username and password). But the hash is serialized/deserialized the same way. Here is a [picture of the client serialized hash](http://i.imgur.com/g5IWcH1.png) and [server serialized hash](http://i.imgur.com/PFTg9zE.png).

Comment: You only read one line from the `$new_socket`, but the serialized hash seems to have several lines.

Comment: @choroba ahh.. I see.. even though I called my var `line`, I thought `$line = <$new_socket>;` would read all it is sent by the client and not only the first line. Is there a way to send the serialized hash through one line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @choroba says in the comments you only read one line in the server, although you can fix it by reading more lines in the server, you might want to have newline as a record delimiter.

You can get the freeze to only use one line by removing the newlines you read from username and password: `chomp($username);` and `chomp($password);`

You can also encode the newlines, although this is a bit hackish, and not fool proof. To encode: `$serializedInfos =~ s/\n/\\n/g;` to decode: `$line =~ s/\\n/\n/g;`

Or you could change to a serialization that only uses one line, like `JSON`, instead of `Storage` that you are currently using.